# multiplying a convergent sequence by a convergent series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta, absolute-convergence

I am trying to prove that if we have $\sum|{r_j}| < R$, and $|\{s_{j,k}\}| \le S $, and if  $\lim_{k \to \infty} s_{j,k} = 0$ for every element j, that the limit as k goes to infinity of $\sum^{\infty}_{j=0}r_j s_{j,k}$
is $0$. I am a bit stuck. I am trying to use basic properties of the convergence of sequences and series as given in Rudin's PMA, but keep running into trouble.

Comment: $|\sum\limits_{j=0}^{\infty}r_js_{j,k}|\leq |\sum\limits_{j=0}^{N}r_js_{j,k}|+S\sum\limits_{j=N+1}^{\infty}|r_j|$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy my apologies, I mislabeled one of the indices by mistake.

Comment: I am a bit confused, isn't S \sum^{\infty}_{j=N+1} | r_j |  still possibly larger than S? How are we showing that the limit of the series converges to 0?